# Rust (the survival game) RCON password alternative

Tags: websocket, steam, rcon

So I have a webapp that manages my rust servers. I need to provide the rcon password in order to use rcon. But for that I need to store the password in my database.

Is there an alternative way to make a connection to rcon, like using OAuth tokens or anything that I'm not aware of? Without saving the password that is a major security issue.

Comment: Yes, there are many options.

Comment: @mousetail I'm looking for an alternative for rust game servers, not the programming language rust

Comment: Your question will most likely get downvoted because of your tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rust Servers (The game) uses a websocket server for the rcon and does not support OAuth. So NO. There is no alternative method authenticating as the password is expected as a `path` in the websocket connection URL.

```
ws://ip:port/password
```